# Client Parse Server Issue

Tags: parse-platform, server

How can I modify this code to run on custom Parse server?

```
public class ParseTutorialApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Parse.initialize(this, "your key", "your key");
        ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);
        // set applicationId, and server server based on the values in the server
        // clientKey is not needed unless explicitly configured
        // any network interceptors must be added with the Configuration Builder given this syntax
        Parse.initialize(new Parse.Configuration.Builder(this)
                .applicationId("yourapplicationid")
                .clientKey("yourkey")

                .server("http://example.com:1337/parse/").build()
        );

    }
```

this will be solve your problem